# How to target a entity by it's name Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to target a entity by its name. Here is the command I a, using:
`execute @e[type=fishing_hook,name=kill] ~~~ kill @e`. My problem is, I got the fishing hook named to 'kill', but this does nothing. If I remove the `name=kill` it works as expected, anyone know how to select a entity by its name in Minecraft Bedrock?

Comment: The fishing hook and fishing rod are two different things, if you name the fishing *rod* using an anvil, the fishing *hook* that comes from it won't be named the same thing. The only way to rename the fishing *hook* is with commands, and since I don't play bedrock, I don't know how to do that :(

Answer (score 1):

By using the `name` argument of a command as you're already doing:

```
execute @e[name=entityNameHere] tp ~ ~10 ~
```

However, and unfortunately, the fishing hook can't be given or summoned in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition , and as a result, **cannot be named** since these are the only commands in Bedrock Edition that enable us to give names to entities.

---

<sub>*You can read more about the commands available in Bedrock Edition on [DigMinecraft](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/).*</sub>